# KVM fastest network between 2 guests

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization

I wonder if there is any way to speed up the network communication between 2 KVM guests on the same physical machine.

Would that help at all if I would configure a separate bridge network for just the two of them (vnet5+vnet6) or is there any way to setup an even faster network between Guests something like unix sockets?

Thanks

Comment: Are you having a performance problem? If so, [you should be asking about that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912).

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to check is that both VMs uses the virtio-net driver. If so, any other tuning you can do at the software switch level is going to be almost irrelevant.

On the other side, a correct guest setup (eg: enabling jumbo frame) will be much more fruitful.